# kWh rate in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I am struggling with being able to analyze the users input for differing rate charges. Could someone steer me in the right direction? Here are the parameters,

less than 1000  $0.052 per kWh used

at least 1000 but less than 1300
$0.052 per kWh for first 1000 kWh used, $0.041 per kWh over 1000 kWh used.

at least 1300 but less than 2000
$0.052 per kWh for first 1000 kWh used, $0.041 per kWh for the next 300 kWh used, $0.035 per kWh over 1300 kWh used.

at least 2000
$0.052 per kWh for first 1000 kWh used, $0.041 per kWh for the next 300 kWh used, $0.035 per kWh for the next 700 kWh used, $0.03 per kWh over 2000 kWh used.

```
 'Get kwh used
    decKwhUsed = CDec(txtKwhUsed.Text)

    'Determine the kwh cost less than 1000 * 0.052
    Select Case decKwhUsed
        Case Is < 1000
            decPreAmt = decKwhUsed * 0.052

        Case >= 1000 And 1300            
            'First 1000 kwh * .052
            If decKwhUsed <= 1000 Then
                decPreAmt1 = decKwhUsed * 0.052
            End If

            'kwh over 1000 * .041
            If decKwhUsed > 1000 Then
                decPreAmt2 = decKwhUsed * 0.041
            End If

            decPreAmt = decPreAmt1 + decPreAmt2

        Case > 1300 And 2000
            'First 1000 kwh * .052
            If decKwhUsed <= 1000 Then
                decPreAmt1 = decKwhUsed * 0.052
            End If

            'kwh over 1000 for the next 300 * .041
            If decKwhUsed >= 1001 And decKwhUsed <= 1300 Then
                decPreAmt2 = decKwhUsed * 0.041
            End If

            'kwh over 1300 * .035
            If decKwhUsed >= 1300 Then
                decPreAmt3 = decKwhUsed * 0.035
            End If

            decPreAmt = decPreAmt1 + decPreAmt2 + decPreAmt3

        Case Is > 2000
            'First 1000 kwh * .052
            If decKwhUsed <= 1000 Then
                decPreAmt1 = decKwhUsed * 0.052
            End If

            'kwh over 1000 for the next 300 * .041
            If decKwhUsed >= 1001 And decKwhUsed <= 1300 Then
                decPreAmt2 = decKwhUsed * 0.041
            End If

            'kwh over 1300 for the next 700 * .035
            If decKwhUsed >= 1301 And decKwhUsed <= 2000 Then
                decPreAmt3 = decKwhUsed * 0.035
            End If

            'kwh over 2000 * 0.03
            If decKwhUsed > 2000 Then
                decPreAmt4 = decKwhUsed * 0.03
            End If

            decPreAmt = decPreAmt1 + decPreAmt2 + decPreAmt3 + decPreAmt4
```

Comment: Does that even compile?  After you read [ask] and take the [tour] you might want to read up on [Select Case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement)

Comment: Plutonix, Yes it compiles, I didn't include the entire code for the program because this is the only portion I'm struggling with.

Comment: Consider posting a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as required by rules of this website. This code you posted doesn't compile. It doesn't matter that you have the more complete version of it that compiles.

Comment: Also it's unclear what are you asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the fixed amounts, no need for `If` statements for them. Only check the tiers and remember that you can only fall into one branch of the `Select Case`, so need to keep checking. For example, if the amount is less than 1000, it will fall into that branch and none of the other branches will be executed. Try this:

```
'Get kwh used
decKwhUsed = CDec(txtKwhUsed.Text)

Select Case decKwhUsed
    Case < 1000
        'Determine the kwh cost less than 1000 * 0.052
        decPreAmt = decKwhUsed * 0.052
    Case < 1300            
        'First 1000 kwh * .052
        decPreAmt = 52

        'kwh over 1000 * .041
        If decKwhUsed > 1000 Then
            decPreAmt = decPreAmt + ((decKwhUsed - 1000) * 0.041)
        End If
    Case < 2000
        'First 1000 kwh * .052 = 52
        'plus next 300 kwh * .041 = 12.3
        decPreAmt = 64.3

        'kwh over 1300 * .035
        If decKwhUsed > 1300 Then
            decPreAmt = decPreAmt + ((decKwhUsed - 1300) * 0.035)
        End If
    Case Else
        'First 1000 kwh * .052 = 52
        'plus next 300 kwh * .041 = 12.3
        'plus next 700 kwh * .035 = 24.5
        decPreAmt = 88.8

        'kwh over 2000 * 0.03
        If decKwhUsed > 2000 Then
            decPreAmt = decPreAmt + ((decKwhUsed - 2000) * 0.03)
        End If
End Select
```

Alternatively, it is easier to read/arrange the requirements differently:

- up to 1000, $0.052 per kWh used.
- over 1000 up to 1300, $0.041 per kWh used.
- over 1300 up to 2000, $0.035 per kWh used.
- over 2000, $0.03 per kWh used.

Now you can already see how easier they are to read, and consequently they are much easier to implement without any `If` statements. Try this, it gives the exact same results as above, but with much less code:

```
'Get kwh used
decKwhUsed = CDec(txtKwhUsed.Text)

Select Case decKwhUsed
    Case > 1000
        'First 1000 kwh * .052 = 52
        'plus kwh over 1000 * .041
        decPreAmt = 52 + ((decKwhUsed - 1000) * 0.041)
    Case > 1300
        'First 1000 kwh * .052 = 52
        'plus next 300 kwh * .041 = 12.3
        'plus kwh over 1300 * .035
        decPreAmt = 64.3 + ((decKwhUsed - 1300) * 0.035)
    Case > 2000
        'First 1000 kwh * .052 = 52
        'plus next 300 kwh * .041 = 12.3
        'plus next 700 kwh * .035 = 24.5
        'plus kwh over 2000 * 0.03
        decPreAmt = 88.8 + ((decKwhUsed - 2000) * 0.03)
    Case Else
        'Determine the kwh cost less than 1000 * 0.052
        decPreAmt = decKwhUsed * 0.052
End Select
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance Racil Hilan. I will try this, I had a feeling I was over-complicating this with all the "IF" statements. And you are very right, rearranging the question makes it much less overwhelming to read and logically try to achieve, thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

If you organize your code a little different, there is a lot shorter way to get you calculation. This code just goes frtom the upper bound and retracts the limit. A running version of this code can be found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UtcqTZ)

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq

Public Module Module1
  public function GetRatesPerKw(kwUsed as Decimal) as Dictionary(Of decimal, integer)
    dim remainingKw = kwUsed
    dim tarifTable as new Dictionary(Of decimal, integer)

    while remainingKw > 0
      if (remainingKw > 2000) then
        tarifTable.Add(0.03, remainingKw - 2000)
        remainingKw = 2000
      else if remainingKw > 1300 then
        tarifTable.Add(0.035, remainingKw - 1300)
        remainingKw = 1300
      else if remainingKw > 1000 then
        tarifTable.Add(0.041, remainingKw - 1000)
        remainingKw = 1000
      else
        tarifTable.Add(0.052, remainingKw)
        remainingKw = 0
      end if
    end while
    return tarifTable
  end function

  public function CalculateTotalPrice(tarifTable as Dictionary(Of decimal, integer)) as Decimal
        return tarifTable.Sum(Function (kvp ) 
            Console.WriteLine("{0:n4} x {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value)
            return kvp.Key * kvp.Value 
          End Function)
  end function

  Public Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("For 900 kw, pay $ {0:n2}", CalculateTotalPrice(GetRatesPerKw(900)))
    Console.WriteLine("For 1200 kw, pay $ {0:n2}", CalculateTotalPrice(GetRatesPerKw(1200)))
    Console.WriteLine("For 1500 kw, pay $ {0:n2}", CalculateTotalPrice(GetRatesPerKw(1500)))
    Console.WriteLine("For 1900 kw, pay $ {0:n2}", CalculateTotalPrice(GetRatesPerKw(1900)))
    Console.WriteLine("For 2100 kw, pay $ {0:n2}", CalculateTotalPrice(GetRatesPerKw(2100)))
    Console.WriteLine("For 4200 kw, pay $ {0:n2}", CalculateTotalPrice(GetRatesPerKw(4200)))
  End Sub
End Module
```

In case at a later time, you would need to extend or change the calculations, you could make the above code still a bit easier, by defining the upperbounds in a dictionary and the value from on those bounds, like so:

```
Option Strict On
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq

Public Module Module1
  Dim tarifs as new Dictionary(Of integer, decimal) from { { 2000, 0.03d }, {1300, 0.035d}, {1000, 0.041d }, {0, 0.052d} }

  public function GetRatesPerKwBasedOnTarifTable(tarifs as Dictionary(Of integer, decimal), kwUsed as integer) as Dictionary(Of decimal, integer)
    dim remainingKw = kwUsed
    dim tarifTable as new Dictionary(Of decimal, integer)

    For Each kvp in tarifs.OrderByDescending(Function(item) item.Key)
      if remainingKw > kvp.Key then
        tarifTable.Add(kvp.Value, remainingKw - kvp.Key)
        remainingKw = kvp.Key
      end if
    Next
    return tarifTable
  end function

  public function CalculateTotalPrice(tarifTable as Dictionary(Of decimal, integer)) as Decimal
        return tarifTable.Sum(Function (kvp ) kvp.Key * kvp.Value)
  end function

  Public Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("For 900 kw, pay $ {0:n2}", CalculateTotalPrice(GetRatesPerKwBasedOnTarifTable( tarifs, 900)))
    Console.WriteLine("For 1200 kw, pay $ {0:n2}", CalculateTotalPrice(GetRatesPerKwBasedOnTarifTable( tarifs, 1200)))
    Console.WriteLine("For 1500 kw, pay $ {0:n2}", CalculateTotalPrice(GetRatesPerKwBasedOnTarifTable( tarifs, 1500)))
    Console.WriteLine("For 1900 kw, pay $ {0:n2}", CalculateTotalPrice(GetRatesPerKwBasedOnTarifTable( tarifs, 1900)))
    Console.WriteLine("For 2100 kw, pay $ {0:n2}", CalculateTotalPrice(GetRatesPerKwBasedOnTarifTable( tarifs, 2100)))
    Console.WriteLine("For 4200 kw, pay $ {0:n2}", CalculateTotalPrice(GetRatesPerKwBasedOnTarifTable( tarifs, 4200)))
  End Sub
End Module
```

I also updated the dotnetfiddle with this code. This version would make it lots more extendable in the future, without the need to add more cases or if statements

Comment: If you had written the version with a dictionary under Option Strict On, it would have pointed out a type mismatch. Also, it is poor style to have a function (in this case `CalculateTotalPrice`) which has side-effects (i.e. the console output). Otherwise I would have given it an upvote.

Comment: Icepickle, this is way more advanced than I am able to follow. I appreciate your help, I'm sure as I advance through to more coding I will learn these higher end techniques, thank you again, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks for point that out, I added the option strict on, and corrected the errors, also removed the debugging statements from the calculate function (on dotnetfiddle pretty much the only option I had :))

Comment: @MB9 The second piece of code is mainly a for loop with some sorting. The advantage of this code is that at a later time you could show the user using your program how the total was calculated. I can see how it looks more complex at first, but if you look through the code, and try to play around with it, I guess you could get the hang of it pretty quickly ;)

Comment: This answer is an overkill for the simple scenario in the question. It is much more complex to read and write than a simple switch, and noticeably slower because it uses a dictionary, a loop, and the stack (function call). This clearly violate the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) (Keep it simple stupid) for the simple scenario in the question. However, it is a very good solution for other scenarios with much more tiers (maybe 10+), or for other requirements (e.g. saving the tiers in the database so they can be changed without changing the code). Upvoted.

Comment: @RacilHilan That's true, as you answered directly to the question already I thought I would supply a different way for implementing it. It might be more complicated,  however, I was trying to consider which other necessities this code might still have in the future or even to support for different customers (eg: private/business customers), so yeah, it *looks* much more complex, however, I would think it is also more future proof

Comment: Agreed, and I'm glad that you provided this elegant solution as I'm sure it will help many readers.